# How to extract all images from a Facebook page?

Tags: javascript, php, proxy

Consider an example page like [this](https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner2/photos_stream)

Now, it displays all the image thumbnails. I click on the thumbnail and then I right click on larger version of image and copy the image location. Is there any way to do it programmatically. I have tried to use goutte to extract links after scraping webpage but it does not extract any link may be because the page is generated dynamically.

Is there some other way to do it?

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.facebook.com/TedTheStoner2/photos_stream');

$crawler->filter('.uiMediaThumb')->each(function ($node) 
{
      echo $node->attr('href').'<br>';
});
```

Comment: can you please post your tried code

Comment: are you trying to increase Hits on ur FB profile? or what?

Comment: @JithinVarghese I have included the code. It wont' be of much help thoguh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should use the facebook graph api for [reading those pictures](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/album/photos).

That way you will be able to get a complete list of images and then [read every single image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo) for more details.

You will not be able to crawl the picture gallery the way you've tried without using a javascript-enabled solution as the pages are rendered by JS on pageload.