# How to obtain images from a facebook page?

Tags: javascript, api, facebook, npm, web-scraping

I'm creating a landing page for an NGO, and I would like to retrieve the photos they upload to their facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/choiceguatemala/photos

I've done my googling but couldn't find anything on techniques.

Is there an official API I could use or a a third party API/npm package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract all images from a Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29691175/how-to-extract-all-images-from-a-facebook-page)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all photos of a page using Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037926/get-all-photos-of-a-page-using-facebook-api)

Comment: Nathan & jsejcksn, I think that API requires me to be the owner of the Facebook page. So it doesn't answer my question. :( I'm not the owner of the Facebook page. It's weird bc their photos are public.

Comment: @CarlosDubón I don't know if there's an *official* package associated with Facebook, but what comes to mind re: npm packages would be puppeteer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63504437/download-multiple-images-with-nodejs-puppeteer)

Comment: _"I think that API requires me to be the owner of the Facebook page."_ - no, it doesn't. A page admin would log in to your app and grant it the necessary permissions, that's how it works. _"It's weird bc their photos are public."_ - not everything available "publicly" via the UI, is also freely accessible via API. Especially after Cambridge Analytica, Facebook changed a lot in that regard, to make automated data gathering on a large scale via API less feasible.